# Instead of color, symbols apears in aws cloudwatch console with winston

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, winston

I am using winston for logging as below.

```
const winston = require('winston');
const {transports, format, createLogger  } = winston;
const { combine,errors, splat,timestamp } = format;

const logger = createLogger({
    level:  process.env.LOG_LEVEL,
    transports: [
        new transports.Console({
            format: combine(
                timestamp({
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
                }),
                errors({stack: true}),
                splat(),
                winston.format.colorize(),
                format.json()
            )
        })
    ]
});

module.exports = {logger};
```

and in console it shows **symbols** instead of **color** as shown below

```
{ 
"message": "apiKeyId: ef12dv3n3b", 
"level": "\u001b[34mdebug\u001b[39m",
"timestamp": "2019-08-20 07:07:16" 
}
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I've just been experimenting with outputting to Cloudwatch from NodeJS too. And found the same issue, with weird character encoding appearing for the level and/or message depending on what combination I used. I assume it is because of the colour too. And found this question.

I guess you can't change the colours.

I found some Chrome extensions (not tried) like 'Colorize CloudWatch' which could be a way round it. I assume they set the colour in the browser based on the level.

I'm currently trying out the WinstonCloudwatch transport instead of Console (https://github.com/lazywithclass/winston-cloudwatch) and so far haven't seen the character encoding issue with that. Though from what I've seen, Cloudwatch *still* controls the colours and so you get a standard grey/green JSON.

This is my current formatter (without colours) I'm experimenting with, set as `messageFormatter: cloudwatchFormat`:

```
const cloudwatchFormat = function (info, opts) {
   const message = info.message;
   const splat = info[Symbol.for('splat')];
   const splatFormatted = splat ? splat.map((s) => (typeof s === 'string' ? s : JSON.stringify(s))) : '';

   return JSON.stringify({
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      level: info.level,
      message: message,
      variables: splatFormatted
   });
}
```